# No resource group found in IBMCloud

Tags: ibm-cloud

I see that, I do not have the Default Resource Group associated to my IBMCloud account. Because of this I can't any resource to my account

When I run command for Viewing resources in a resource group, this is what I see:

```
PS C:\Users\SURANJANNANDI> ibmcloud resource service-instances -g Default
Retrieving instances with type service_instance in resource group Default in all locations under account Suranjan Nandi's Account as surnandi@in.ibm.com...
FAILED No resource group found
```

Did anybody have similar issues? Please advise how to fix this.

Comment: Your resource group probably is called `default` not `Default`. So I'd try also `ibmcloud resource service-instances -g default` or issue `ibmcloud resource groups` to list all resource groups in your account.

Answer (score 3):

Try the command: ibmcloud resource groups

Or in the ibm cloud console, https://cloud.ibm.com/,  check out the Manage > Account at the top.  Click Resource groups on the left and see the list of possible resource groups.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. The only way I could have Watson Studio working was through signing up with a new account in the Data Pak portal. There you may also manage your account (which didn't work for me, but may work for you).